# how to simplify my cypher with several relationships and the path with several nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
match p=(a:ACCT_NO)
-[r1:TRX_TO]-(n1:ACCT_NO)
-[r2:TRX_TO]-(n2:ACCT_NO)
-[r3:TRX_TO]-(n3:ACCT_NO)
-[r4:TRX_TO]-(b:ACCT_NO)
-[rb:BELONG_TO]->(c1:CUSTOM_NO{sensitivity:'1'})
-[:RELATE_TO*0..2]-(c2:CUSTOM_NO)
where r1.trxAmt > 10000 and r2.trxAmt > 10000 and r3.trxAmt > 10000 and r4.trxAmt > 10000
and a.acctNo in $doubtAcct
and not n1.acctNo in $fliterAcct
and not n2.acctNo in $fliterAcct
and not n3.acctNo in $fliterAcct
return p;
```

i want to find the path between a and b, but in the path there are no nodes in the list of $fliterAcct 
and trxAmt the attribute of relationships is greater than 10000.

my question is how to simplify my cypher? 
because i don't want to find path with n1,n2,n3 and r1,r2,r3 if i need to search in several relationships.
whether i can use the pattern like [r:TRX_TO*...3] (actually i try,but the error is Type mismatch: expected Any, 
Map, Node or Relationship but was List (line 2, column 7 (offset: 54)) "where r.trxAmt > 10000")

Comment: You said you want the path between a and b, but your path continues beyond that with `rb`, `c1`, and the relationship to `c2`. Do you want that in the path too, or do you want to restrict `b` to a node that is connected to other nodes in such a way (which suggests we should use the WHERE clause for this part of the path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified query:

```
MATCH p = (a:ACCT_NO)-[rels:TRX_TO*4]-(:ACCT_NO)-[:BELONG_TO]->(:CUSTOM_NO{sensitivity:'1'})-[:RELATE_TO*0..2]-(:CUSTOM_NO)
WHERE a.acctNo in $doubtAcct AND
  ALL(r IN rels WHERE r.trxAmt > 10000) AND
  NONE(n IN NODES(p)[1..3] WHERE n.acctNo in $fliterAcct)
RETURN p;
```

[EDITED]

Or, since the usage of identifiers for variable-length relationships has been [deprecated since version 3.2](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/deprecations-additions-removals-compatibility/#cypher-deprecations-additions-removals-3.2), you can do this instead:

```
MATCH p = (a:ACCT_NO)-[:TRX_TO*4]-(:ACCT_NO)-[:BELONG_TO]->(:CUSTOM_NO{sensitivity:'1'})-[:RELATE_TO*0..2]-(:CUSTOM_NO)
WHERE a.acctNo in $doubtAcct AND
  ALL(r IN RELATIONSHIPS(p)[0..3] WHERE r.trxAmt > 10000) AND
  NONE(n IN NODES(p)[1..3] WHERE n.acctNo in $fliterAcct)
RETURN p;
```

Comment: This is indeed easier...but be aware that binding a variable-length relationship to a variable is deprecated (`rels`, in this case), and will be removed at some point in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I have added an alternate query.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, a variable-length pattern is the right way to go, but you'll need to use a different approach to ensure that all nodes and relationships adhere to the restrictions you want.

```
match p=(a:ACCT_NO)-[:TRX_TO*4]-(b:ACCT_NO)-[rb:BELONG_TO]->(c1:CUSTOM_NO{sensitivity:'1'})-[:RELATE_TO*0..2]-(c2:CUSTOM_NO)
where a.acctNo in $doubtAcct and all(rel in relationships(p) where type(rel) <> 'TRX_TO' OR r.trxAmt > 10000)
 and none(node in nodes(p) where node in $fliterAcct)
return p;
```